# Is there a limit on a user setting size in .NET application?

Tags: .net, wpf, application-settings, settings

I would like to serialize my object with many values as string(xml) into user settings. Is there a limit on how large a "string" user setting can be in a .NET application?

I am extending `ApplicationSettingsBase` to save my settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit limit imposed by the application settings code.  The only limits are really those of the backing storage (typically the file system).

While that allows for a very large string to be used I would caution from going overboard here.  Just because it's possible doesn't mean it should be done :)

Comment: Max of 2gb per object I think